# TensorFlow error: funcsigs module doesn't have signature attribute

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have installed TensorFlow and wanted to check the installation. Here is the interaction with the python console.

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov 20 2015, 02:00:19) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/shehab1/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/shehab1/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 106, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.platform import test
  File "/home/shehab1/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/test.py", line 81, in <module>
    import mock                # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top,unused-import
  File "/home/shehab1/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    import mock.mock as _mock
  File "/home/shehab1/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 81, in <module>
    inspectsignature = funcsigs.signature
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'signature'
>>>
```

Could anyone please tell what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Python too old? Try `from funcsigs import signature`. Works in 2.7.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Yaroslav noted, this is most likely from running too old a version of Python, or you don't have the funcsigs package installed.  For the latter, try `pip install funcsigs`